# Flutter compatibility blocks the app from running

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using flutter and firebase, and when i run the app i get this message in the debug console:
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(25412): Compat change id reported: 3400644; UID 10192; state: DISABLED

I tried to look for solutions to pick compatible versions for each dependency i'm using, and i didn't find a useful solution.